# Append converted number to existing string

Tags: assembly

I have used one simple algorithm for converting number to string found here on SO which I have adjusted for my own purposes, but it doesn't exactly do what I need. 
I have a string:

```
string point, "xxx points"
```

And constant:

```
const10    dd 10
points     dd 50  ; range from 0 - 990
```

The adjusted routine

```
mov eax, [points] ; number to be converted
  .convNum:      
      push eax
      push edx
      xor edx,edx       
      div dword [const10]  ;eax = result, edx = remainder
      cmp eax, dword 0         ; test of the res
      je .print               
      jmp .convNum   
  .print:
      lea eax,[edx+'0']
      mov [point], dword eax ; need to replace xxx in string by number
      pop edx
      pop eax
```

This one doesn't work as intended, because it shows only one digit, which I understand, but I am not able to change the routine in a way I want.

**EDIT:**

 Adding another version of code

```
push eax
    push edx
    mov eax, [points]
  .convNum:             
      xor edx,edx       
      div dword [const10]  
      lea eax,[edx+'0']
      mov ecx,[counter]
      cmp ecx, 1
      jne .next
      mov [point+2], byte al
      mov eax,[points]
      div dword [const10]
      jmp .again
      .next:
      cmp ecx, 2
      jne .next2
      mov [point+1], byte al
      mov eax,[points]
      div dword [const10]
      div dword [const10]
      jmp .again
      .next2:
      mov ecx,[p_bodu]
      cmp ecx, 100
      jb .kend
      mov [point], byte al    
      jmp .kend
      .again:
      inc ecx
      mov [counter],ecx
      jmp .convNum
      .kend:
      pop edx
      pop eax
```

This code takes the number from lowest to highest. Numbers like 120 convert well, but number like 130,150 convert to 630, 650, again number 140 converts well

Comment: The word you're looking for is not "Justified."

Comment: Yop, indeed, I will edit the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to replace the "xxx". Add the space ("xxx ") and you want to replace 4 bytes (= 1 dword) which fits into a 32-bit register. The register will be stored "little endian". If you store a 0x20303531 to the memory it will appear there as 0x31 0x35 0x30 0x20 which is the ASCII code for "150 ".

Here is an example for NASM:

```
SECTION .data
    point      db "xxx points", 0
    const10    dd 10
    points     dd 150  ; range from 0 - 990

SECTION .text
...
  mov ebx, 0x20202020       ; 4 spaces
  mov eax, [points]         ; number to be converted
.convNum:
  xor edx,edx
  div dword [const10]       ; eax = result, edx = remainder
  shl ebx, 8                ; shift last result
  mov bl, dl                ; copy remainder to the last byte of EBX
  or bl, '0'                ; to ASCII
  test eax, eax             ; test of the res
  je .print

  jmp .convNum
.print:
  mov [point], ebx          ; need to replace xxx in string by number
...
```

I can't post a full program because I don't know your operating system.

Comment: @rkhb Very nice solution. (+1) But why waste an extra `jmp` and not write `test eax,eax` `jne .convNum`.

Comment: @Fifoernik: Because I wanted to be as near as possible to the original of the OP. I always presume that a MCVE is just a part of a bigger program and such a thing has its relevance - anyhow.

Answer (score 4):

You keep pushing EAX and EDX in a loop. You only need to do this once.

Move the *.convNum* label 2 lines lower:

```
   mov eax, [points] ; number to be converted
   push eax
   push edx
.convNum:      
   xor edx,edx       
   div dword [const10]  ;eax = result, edx = remainder
   cmp eax, dword 0         ; test of the res
   jne .convNum   
.print:
```

Also note that you should write a byte instead of a dword:

```
mov [point], al ;
```

The code you wrote will only process the highest digit of the value provided. To continu retrieving lower placed digits you need to subtract the current digit times (a multiple of) 10 from the number and repeat the code.

Comment: You are right, however output doesn't change. String appends only number `5` not the `0` after

Comment: You do realize that the purpose of this code is to extract __the highest digit only__ of the number provided?  To continu with a lower placed digit subtract (digit * 10) and repeat the code!